# How can I make the Typescript checker select the correct union type based on a property

Tags: typescript

I have a data grid where a user could group data. This means that data for a row could either be the type of their data, or the one for a grouping row.

That means in some situations the user will have to check the type of row to perform the right action - for example returning a unique ID for the row.

The problem is that TS checker only selects the correct type if the property exists in BOTH types:

```
interface Athlete {
  id: string
  name: string
  // Works with this but inconvenient to force the user to
  // add this to all their items
  // isGroup: false
}

interface GroupRow {
  isGroup: true
  groupId: string
}

type Row = Athlete | GroupRow

function getRowId(row: Row) {
  return row.isGroup ? row.groupId : row.id // TS Error
}
```

Playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJgBYBsKWQbwFgAoZZYAEwC5kBnMKUAcxLJDgFsIb7GQXSyAPRDkAFQzBayCnDBxykDsgBkyMAE8ADiinItUAPYA3ShArIARhvUYUAV1rQANK2GjgYAOTTQCQyDGECDAwWDqhsgccADWKJgQylr24Zh6AQB0biLktADiRvZaNPBYTiQAviQkoJCwiCgFhkUASoYA7gRuUk1FNAz2EG5MhVoAktR0DMyV1cSaOshtnQC8aJg4eAA%20yL1ay3Mw9iAIYMAByEy4yxMAFEbtNMsAlF2CULj2UCDIDxk9o2QAH5fh0MiNmuMLDQ-pRKkA)

It seems the TS checker should be able to determine the correct type since `isGroup` will never be true (or defined) in `Athlete`, but unfortunately it can't. And I don't want to have to:

a) Make users add a `isGroup: false` to the `Athlete` type and their data

b) Make the user implicitly cast to the correct type every time `row` is referenced e.g. `(row as GroupRow).isGroup ? (row as GroupRow).groupId : (row as Athlete).id`

How can I get the TS checker to infer the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) to narrow types:

```
function getRowId(row: Row) {
  return 'isGroup' in row ? row.groupId : row.id
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJgBYBsKWQbwFgAoZZYAEwC5kBnMKUAcxLJDgFsIb7GQXSyAPRDkAFQzBayCnDBxykDsgBkyMAE8ADiinItUAPYA3ShArIARhvUYUAV1rQANK2GjgYAOTTQCQyDGECDAwWDqhsgccADWKJgQylr24Zh6AQB0biLktADiRvZaNPBYTiQAviQkoJCwiCgFhkUASoYA7gRuUk1FNAz2EG5MhVoAktR0DMyV1cSaOshtnQC8aJg4eAA+yL1ay3Mw9iAIYMAByEy4yxMAFEbtNMsAlF2CULj2UCDIXj2jXnIPweyAA-MgHhkRs1xhYaJDKLNiCQgA)